# Yii2 method name from db is working in gridview, but not in detailview, why?

Tags: php, yii2, formatter

I have this working in GridView:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'attribute',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return \Yii::$app->formatter->{$model->format}($model->attribute);
    },
],
```

I want to implement basically the same but into DetailView:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'attribute',
    'value' => \Yii::$app->formatter->{$model->format}($model->attribute),
],
```

`$model->format` is coming from DB and is e.g. `asDecimal`.
In DetailView I'm getting the following error:

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Method name must be a string

How can I avoid this problem? Can you please point me to the right direction? Thank you!

UPDATE: it's also not working in index pages. It's working only in views, generated with giiant, in gridviews of related data. I see these are somehow strange echoed gridviews, but what is the key difference between a normal gridview, and the one like that:

```
<?=
'<div class="table-responsive">'
. \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
    'layout' => '{summary}{pager}<br/>{items}{pager}',
    'dataProvider' => new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
```

Comment: Make sure you `$model->format` is not empty and it is string.

Comment: It's sure it's not empty, but how can I make sure of that it is a string?

Comment: I mean it's definitely a varchar in the db, but somehow maybe really not handled as a string basically by yii

Comment: check what is return by `$model->format`. Add in question also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Yii 2.0.11 you can use closures in `DetailView` in the same way as in `GridView`:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'attribute',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return \Yii::$app->formatter->{$model->format}($model->attribute);
    },
],
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-widgets#detail-view

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't make any difference, the error is still there

Comment: oh man, it should be `$model->relation->format`... now it works. Many thanks for your comments!